# Applying the definition of a limit of a sequence, Real Analysis - Bartle

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I would like to know, if I am using the $\epsilon-K$ definition of a limit correctly in the below problem.

> Use the definition of limit of a sequence to establish the following limit.
>
> $\lim{\left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right)=0}$

**Proof.**

We would like to prove that,

$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists{K}\in{\mathbb{N}})$ s.t. $({n\ge{K}})\implies{\frac{n}{n^2+1}}<\epsilon$

We can write:

$\frac{n}{n^2+1}<\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}$

It suffices to have:

$\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon\implies{n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$

Since $\epsilon>0$ is an arbitrary positive real, by the archimedean property there exists $K\in{\mathbb{N}}$, such that

$K(\epsilon)>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$

Thus, for all $n\ge{K}$, $\frac{n}{n^2+1}<\epsilon$. Hence, proved.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: You need to show that $|n/(n^2+1)|<\epsilon$, but instead you showed that $n/(n^2+1)<\epsilon$. A simple fix might be to show that $n/(n^2+1)>0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Other than that, your proof looks fine to me. I might format it a bit differently to be easier to the reader also.

Comment: @Birdman2246, yes that's correct. I assumed that $\frac{n}{n^2+1}>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I will add that to my proof in my notes. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Quasar You're welcome.

Comment: small but important note: you said "we must have", but it should be "it suffices to have" since all you really need is "n/(n^2+1) < epsilon"; you don't need "1/n < epsilon"

Answer (score 1):

I am currently teaching a course on sequences and series, in which questions like this come up frequently on homework and exams.  (The midterm I gave last week asked students to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^3+n^2+n} = 0$ 
directly from the definition.)

I would be very happy with your solution and mark it fully correct.  In terms of improving your writing in very minor ways, I would suggest writing "there exists $K = K(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $K > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$": having tipped your hat to the dependence of $K$ on $\epsilon$, it is more standard to henceforth write it as $K$.